# Read custom config setting from config file of application deployed on Azure

Tags: c#-4.0, azure

I would like to read custom setting which i have done in ServiceConfiguration.cscfg & ServiceDefinition.csdef and want to read that setting by code in C#.

For that i created REST call to get deployment as per mentioned on [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460804.aspx)

In that xml response **configuration** is 64 base encoded string, i think my custom setting lies within there (correct me if i am wrong!), if i need application id then i can directly read **Private ID** from that xml but ho can i rad my custom setting?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
    <Name>deployment-name</Name>
         .......
         .......
<Configuration>base-64-encoded-configuration-file</Configuration>
         .......
         .......
  </Deployment>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know for now the customized configuration section is not support. But maybe you can serialize your configuration into one CSCFG setting and deserialize it in your code.